# how to screen count in sql server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

[image]
in my sql server i am able to open three window at a time.. in Google chrome i can open lot of window.i f i open new window automatically decrees the size of rest of all window.like that i want to sett my sql server.now only three window is showing my sq l server. if i open new window i want to show that in sql server(but tab size should decrees),is there any setting for that?
if any one know how to do that.please help me to find out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one short answer is **NO**

but you can set options for what to display in tabs text so tabs will be shorter and you will have more tabs open. to set this option you can go to

```
click Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >>  Editor Tab and Status Bar.
```

Check out the Tab Text options

You can uncheck the database name, login name, and server name because those are shown in the status bar anyway.  Then, if you wanna get fancy, change the status bar location to Top – it’s right above the Tab Text options

Ref: [Fixing SQL Server Management Studio’s Tab Text](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/06/fixing-sql-server-management-studios-tab-text/)

Comment: this on is okey sir..is there any way to minimize that tab while opening the new tab?

Comment: means do u want open a tab and don't want to give the focus to it ??

Comment: i mean i want to open new tab.that time automatic decrees size of all remaining tab.like in google chrom,if i open new tabe in google chrom remaining all tabs size decrese

Comment: sir..that also having some limit right..?? in that case if i open 15 window i can able to see all window at a time?